# NuGet Restore fails for Microsoft.Azure.Kinect.BodyTracking.Dependencies.cuDNN

Tags: azure, kinect, kinect-sdk, azurekinect

I am trying to run C++ code for Azure Kinect Body Tracking samples on Windows available from Microsoft on Git. I have latest NVIDIA drivers installed on my system. While trying to build the project in Visual Studio, NuGet restore for Microsoft.Azure.Kinect.BodyTracking.Dependencies.cuDNN fails for me with a message "could not find a part of path build/native/Microsoft.Azure.Kinect.BodyTracking.Dependencies.cuDNN.targets".

On the other hand, the body tracking viewer app works fine for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve this by reinstalling the Visual Studio. Not sure what was failing but it got resolved after fresh install.